# Symantec Workspace Virtualization SVSCMD Viewing Delete List Item Entries

Tags: command-line, scripting, symantec

When viewing the layer properties for an XPF there is a tab called "Delete Entries" is there a way I can use the command line to see if there are any entries in the System Delete List for a layer?